# tabs.executeScript - how can I tell if content script was being injected?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I inject content scripts into websites programmatically using `browser.tabs.executeScript`. This will return a Promise, but in case of its rejection there seems to be no way of differentiating between the following 2 cases:

1. The content script couldn't be injected (i.e. for missing host
   permission)
2. An error occured on script **update**parsing**end:update**(but the script was being injected)

I'm only interested in whether the script was being injected or not.

The argument passed to the `catch` is an Error object.
`catch(e => console.log(e.toString())` will output the error message, which can either be a reason for an injection failure (i.e. `Missing host permission`) or an error that occurred **update**reading the script**end:update**.

```
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
        file: '../path/to/content-script.js',
        frameId: 0,
        runAt: 'document_idle'
    })
        .catch(e => console.log(e.toString()));
```

So, for example if the content script is as follows:

```
    window.document.body.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked body'), false);
    bla.bla();
```

then the Promise is being rejected, since `bla.bla` is undefined - but the script was being injected successfully.

In case the content script couldn't be injected I'd like to notify the user with the corresponding error message.
But when an error occurred **update**that is unrelated to whether the script could be injected**end:update**, while the script was being injected, I don't want to notify the user, but handle it silently.
Is there a way to differentiate between those 2 cases?

**EDIT:** I came up with an indirect solution: In case the returned Promise was rejected I try to send a message to the content script. If this fails then the background script "knows" that no content script was being injected -> notify user.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the Promise works....

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: '../path/to/content-script.js',
  frameId: 0,
  runAt: 'document_idle'
})
.catch(e => console.log(e.toString()));
```

`catch` in above will catch errors if the `tabs.executeScript` failed to inject. It may also show some errors when parsing the file in order to inject, if the JS file has parsing errors (invalid JS). It has nothing to do with what '*../path/to/content-script.js*' will be doing afterwards.

So once it was injected, then above Promise is fulfilled.

If the injected script has a **sync** return, then it can be received by the `tabs.executeScript` via `then()` e.g.

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: '../path/to/content-script.js',
  frameId: 0,
  runAt: 'document_idle'
})
.then(result => {})
.catch(e => console.log(e.toString()));
```

In case of **async** functions such as `.addEventListener` which will happen later, then is nothing returned to `tabs.executeScript`

To catch errors in the content scripts, you can generate the error message within the content script or send a message to background script i.e. `sendMessage` & `onMessage.addListener`

> [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript#Return_value)
>   A Promise that will be fulfilled with an array of objects,
>   representing the result of the script in every injected frame.
>   The result of the script is the last evaluated statement, which is
>   similar to what would be output (the results, not any console.log()
>   output) if you executed the script in the Web Console. For example,
>   consider a script like this:
>
> ```
> var foo='my result';foo;
> ```

```
browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
  file: '../path/to/content-script.js',
  frameId: 0,
  runAt: 'document_idle'
})
.then(result => {
  // result is returned by the Promise
  if (result === []) { 
    // it was fine but there was nothing to return
  }
  else if (result[0]) {
    // result[0] is return from the promise
  }
})
.catch(e => console.log(e.toString()));
```

Now if you want a return (it must be sync or else you have to tie it to another Promise), return something from *'../path/to/content-script.js'*

Comment: But `catch` will also catch errors from the content script **even though the script was being injected**: For my above content script example `catch` will output "Error: bla is not defined", while clicking on the corresponding page the browser console will output "clicked body" -> so clearly the script was being injected.

Comment: @user1521685 the catch can show JavaScript errors in the code when reading the code in order to inject it. That is only some errors not all. In other words errors related to parsing the JS file you are trying to inject (not related to the content).

Comment: Yes, I know that it has nothing to do with what happens in the content script after the injection (sorry if I haven't expressed myself properly). And I also know that the `catch` will show errors in the code while parsing it. But this is exactly the problem: There is no way of telling by the returned Promise if the script was being injected.

Comment: @user1521685 .. yes there is .. I will add an example to my answer

Comment: Sorry, but in my example the `then` callback won't even be invoked, instead the `catch` is catching the error "Error: bla is not defined". So again: I don't get last evaluated statement but an error catched by `catch` -> this is prove that catching an error is not equivalent with "script wasn't been injected" ;)

Comment: @user1521685 If there is an error, then it goes to `catch()` if no error then it goes to `then()`. You have to fix the error first. It is not possible to say anything without seeing the problem. If you haven't defined `bla.bla()` then you must define it first.

Comment: OK, there seems to be a misunderstanding. That was just an example. If I know about an error I'd fix it right away, but the content script is Webpack bundled from about a dozen scripts. I.e.: one error some user reported was `document.body is null`. I will keep my workaround for now, but thanks a lot for trying to help, I appreciate it :)

Comment: @user1521685 `document.body is null` happens when script is injected before the document is loaded. Try injecting it later.

Comment: Ah OK, so `document_idle` will only execute it when the document is complete, but it is unrelated to the time the script is loaded? That'd explain a lot! Thanks, I think that might be a very helpful clue :) I feel kinda stupid now, didn't know that one was able to load the script that early on. So I have to listen to the change of the tab's `status` via `browser.tabs.onUpdated`

Comment: This doesn't solve the original problem, but it helps me fixing an even bigger issue :)

Comment: Hm, double-checked my source code - I'm already doing that: When a tab's URL has been updated I check the tab's status and if its !== 'complete' I wait for the update of the status before injecting the script. So, no idea how the document isn't loaded at this time - thought that's what the status 'complete' means..

Comment: @user1521685 There could be a conflict between various async API you are using or some other thing which is difficult to guess without checking the code.

Comment: Will switch from `tabs.onUpdated` to `webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded`. This seems to assure both that document is loaded and DOM is ready (`document_idle`) and has the advantage that it fires on URL change of iFrames (as opposed to the former).

Comment: @user1521685 There should be no need to use 2 API `webNavigation` & `tabs.executeScript` and that can lead into conflict sine event would be fired in the correct order. `tabs.executeScript` is the only one you should need and it will run at the right time. The error should not be related to this. The comment area is not the right place to discuss it.

Comment: You are right, posted another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56935506/how-to-make-sure-a-content-script-will-be-loaded-into-each-document-using-tabs-e)